# Returns list index out of range when i iterate through my list

Tags: python, list, range

```
inp = [1,2,3,5,6]

def o(k):

    x =[]
    for item in k:
        if item != k[item-1] and item != item+1:
            x.append(item)
```

When I try to run the code with my input it just says 
"list out of range"

Answer (score 0):

Hi based on your code I understand that you are working on the assumption that `item` is the index of the array. But that is not the way the `for item in k:` loop works in python. On each iteration item will be the next 'element' of the array rather than the next 'index'. Also `item != item + 1` does not make any sense since it will be always true. I think you meant to write `k[item] != k[item + 1]`.

Comment: How would I iterate it then?I'm trying to check if the next element matches the current element+1

Comment: @ALPHA_BOSS Please explain your logic. I am assuming that you want to find all elements that are equal to the next element in your input array . right?

Comment: I'm trying to find elements not equal